HDFS + Using very large disks with HDFS
from my understanding Using 20-30TB disks with HDFS can present some challenges, but it can also be managed effectively with proper configuration
using 20-30TB disks with HDFS is possible, it requires careful consideration of block size, rebuild times, data distribution, metadata management, and performance. Proper planning and configuration can help mitigate these challenges.
Performance: Large disks can lead to longer seek times and potentially impact performance, especially for workloads that require frequent random access.
based on above can we intend to use disks of 20T-30T on our new data nodes machines?
Note we intend to install from scratch 16 data nodes machines based on DELL HW , when each data node should contain 12 NON-RAID disks (when each disk size is ~22T)


so disks like 20T or 40T isn't a problem in HDFS filesystem from performance side ?

Your post is "Using disks of this size with HDFS requires planning. Using disks of this size with HDFS requires these specific plans. Based on what I just said can we use disks of this size in our machines." You've given us no details about your specific requirements that would allow us to provide even advice. However, this question is also asking our opinion, which is off topic here. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear and complete.
